# Lock two mutex at same time

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I'm trying to implement a multi-in multi-out interthread channel class. I have three mutexes: `full` locks when buffer is full. `empty` locks when buffer is empty. `th` locks when anyone else is modifying buffer. My single IO program looks like

```
operator<<(...){
  full.lock()        // locks when trying to push to full buffer
  full.unlock()      // either it's locked or not, unlock it
  th.lock()
  ...
  empty.unlock()     // it won't be empty
  if(...)full.lock() // it might be full
  th.unlock()
operator>>(...){
  // symmetric
}
```

This works totally fine for single IO. But for multiple IO, when consumer thread unlocks `full`, all provider thread will go down, only one will obtain `th` and buffer might be full again because of that single thread, while there's no full check anymore. I can add a `full.lock()` again of course, but this is endless. Is there anyway to lock `full` and `th` at same time? I do see a similar question about this, but I don't see order is the problem here.

Comment: You use mutexes improperly hense the problem. No, you cannot lock 2 mutexes atomically, you need semaphores. For example System V semaphore would work as inteded, but that's OS specific.

Comment: if you've got a c++17 library there is always [`std::scoped_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock)

Comment: I think you want to use condition_variables instead of some of those mutexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't atomically lock two mutexes.

Additionally, it looks like you are locking a mutex in one thread and then unlocking it in another. That's not allowed.

I suggest switching to condition variables for this problem. Note that it's perfectly fine to have one mutex associated with multiple condition variables.

Comment: I thought you could with defer_lock. i.e. unique_lock<mutex> l1{m1, defer_lock}; unique_lock<mutex> l2{m2, defer_lock}; lock(l1, l2); // lock both at the same time

Comment: @Ant std::lock(l1, l2) would guarantee a consistent locking order, yet the mutexes would still be locked one after the other, that is non-atomically.

Comment: 1) Even two separate statements would provide a consistent locking order; the problem is that i can lead to deadlock. 2) in the book "The c++ programming language", Stroustrup writes "It is not uncommon to need to simultaneously access several resources to perform some action. This can lead to deadlock. For example, if thread1 acquires mutex1 and then tries to acquire mutex2
while thread2 acquires mutex2 and then tries to acquire mutex1, then neither task will ever proceed further. The standard library offers help in the form of an operation for acquiring several locks simultaneously"

Comment: ... and then reports the example with defer_lock and lock(l1, l2). Doesn't that mean that mutexes are both locked at the same time?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, use `std::lock(full , th);`, this could avoid some deadlocks

for example:
thread1:

```
full.lock();
th.lock();
```

thread2:

```
th.lock();
full.lock();
```

this could cause a deadlock, but the following don't:

thread1:

```
std::lock(full, th);
```

thread2:

```
std::lock(th, full);
```

Comment: This may avoid deadlock but would not solve race condition problem as 2 mutexes would not be locked atomically.

Comment: @Slava there's not race because, uh, these are mutexes.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes using mutexes does not automatically eliminate race, only if you use them properly.

Comment: @Slava please explain how you can have two mutex operations racing.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes easily, for example mutex `m1` is used as signal "data available", `m2` to lock data. thread 1 locks `m1` and `m2` and pushes data. thread 2 checks `m1` it is locked - data available, then locks `m2` and unconditionally reads data.

Comment: What you described is not relevant in the context of this answer. Both threads lock both mutexes, and both threads do so in a deadlock-free manner. Can you explain how such a problem happens under these conditions?

Comment: @Slava Mutexes shouldn't be used as a "signal" at all. Instead use condition variables for that.

Comment: @ratchetfreak exactly and as I said before mutexes have to be used properly, and that's why providing answer how to avoid deadlock with locking 2 mutexes does not provide any value to this question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot lock two mutexes at once, but you can use a `std::condition_variable` for the waiting threads and invoke `notify_one` when you are done.
See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) for further details.

Comment: while you can't lock both at the exact same time you can use a [`std::scoped_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) if your library already has it, if not I'm sure boost has something equivalent

Comment: @Mgetz That's definitely another valid approach. Would you like me to add it to the answer?

Comment: @Mgetz how `scoped_lock` would help here? Whole idea of using mutexes this way is wrong, does not matter how they locked/unlocked manually or through RAII helper

Comment: @skypjack it's probably worthwhile yes

Comment: @Slava scoped lock does deadlock prevention and tries to acquire both at the same time. Moreover it ensures that both will be released if you leave the scope for any reason. Ensuring you shouldn't be able to dead lock because you forgot to release earlier. Also the OP asked "Can I" not "Is this a good idea?"

Comment: You can also create another mutex to guard lock acquisition, that way you can ensure atomicity

Comment: @Mgetz avoiding deadlock will not make this operation atomic with all related problems. I doubt it would help here. It will not aquire both **at the same time**

Comment: @Slava doesn't matter. What matters is that the observable behavior is the same. Please do read up on `scoped_lock`. Even what you _would_ consider "atomic" is never completely atomic at the hardware level. It's about observable guarantees.

Answer (score -1):

Functonality you try to achieve would require something similar to System V semaphores, where group of operations on semaphors could be applied atomically. In your case you would have 3 semaphores:

- semaphore 1 - locking, initialized to 0
- semaphore 2 - counter of available data, initialized to 0
- semaphore 3 - counter of available buffers, initialized how much buffers you have

then push operation would do this group to lock:

- check semaphore 1 is 0
- increase semaphore 1 by +1
- increase semaphore 2 by +1
- decrease semaphore 3 by -1

then

- decrease semaphore 1 by -1

to unlock. then to pull data first group would be changed to:

- check semaphore 1 is 0
- increase semaphore 1 by +1
- decrease semaphore 2 by -1
- increase semaphore 3 by +1

unlock is the same as before. Using mutexes, which are special case semaphores  most probably would not solve your problem this way. First of all they are binary ie only have 2 states but more important API does not provide group operations on them. So you either find semaphore implementation for your platform or use single mutex with condition variable(s) to signal waiting threads that data or buffer is available.